# Shared Tootlip (areaspline & spline) Not Working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The tooltip 'shared' property is not working and I believe my code to be correct. I would like to see if perhaps I overlooked something before I submit it as a bug on github.

Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/engemasa/z746turz/

```
//JavaScript
var chartOne = Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
  chart : {
    zoomType : 'x',
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0)'
  },
  tooltip : {
    shared: true,
    crosshairs: true,
    xDateFormat: "%b %e, '%y"
  },
  plotOptions: {
    areaspline : {
      fillColor: {
        linearGradient: {
          x1: 0,
          y1: 0,
          x2: 0,
          y2: 1
        },
        stops: [
          [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
          [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
        ]
      },
      marker: {
        radius: 2
      },
      lineWidth: 1,
      states: {
        hover: {
          lineWidth: 1
        }
      },
      threshold: null
    }
  },
  xAxis : {
    type : 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis : {
    title : {
      text : null
    }
  },
  series : [{
    type : 'areaspline',
    name: 'Sales',
    data : randomData()
  }, {
    type : 'spline',
    name : 'Previous Year',
    data : randomData(),
    color: "#990000"
  }]
});
```

Comment: The x values of your two series appear to be slightly different.  If you want to share the tool tip, they must be identical. Definitely not a bug.

Comment: I did NOT think about that! I forgot that I was using moment for time/date and after looking at the data, the x value was 'slightly' different... A bit odd though.

Series 1: 1459483200344 (Fri, 01 Apr 2016 04:00:00.344 GMT)
Series 2: 1459483200348 (Fri, 01 Apr 2016 04:00:00.348 GMT)

Thank you for showing me that I'm not completely insane!